# Same connection string works fine in sqldeveloper, but, throws IO exception from a standalone JDBC program

Tags: java, jdbc, ojdbc

Connection string used:
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCPS)(HOST=hostName)(PORT=1546))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=serviceName)))

Connects to DB successfully from sqldeveloper. Fails with java standalone application with the following error.

```
SQLException >>>>>>,e
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset
[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@76be458c
IO Error: Connection reset
IO Error: Connection reset
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset
```

ojdbc version used

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved by upgrading ojdbc to latest version

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        <version>12.2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```